# Why no access to texture lod in fragment shader

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, texture2d, glsles, level-of-detail

I'm trying to come to terms with the level of detail of a mipmapped texture in an OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shader.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17917340/1468366) it is not possible to use the `bias` parameter to `texture2D` to access a specific level of detail in the fragment shader. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7391241/1468366) the level of detail is instead automatically computed from the parallel execution of adjacent fragments. I'll have to trust that that's the way how things work.

What I cannot understand is the *why* of it. ***Why* isn't it possible to access a specific level of detail, when doing so should be very simple indeed? *Why* does one have to rely on complicated fixed functionality instead?**

To me, this seems very counter-intuitive. After all, the whole OpenGL related stuff evolves away from fixed functionality. And OpenGL ES is intended to cover a broader range of hardware than OpenGL, therefore only support the simpler versions of many things. So I would perfectly understand if developers of the specification had decided that the LOD parameter is mandatory (perhaps defaulting to zero), and that it's up to the shader programmer to work out the appropriate LOD, in whatever way he deems appropriate. Adding a function which does that computation automagically seems like something I'd have expected in desktop OpenGL.

Not providing direct access to a specific level doesn't make any sense to me at all, no matter how I look at it. Particularly since that `bias` parameter indicates that we are indeed allowed to tweak the level of detail, so apparently this is not about fetching data from memory only for a single level for a bunch of fragments processed in parallel. I can't think of any other reason.

---

Of course, *why* questions tend to attract opinions. But since opinion-based answers are not accepted on Stack Overflow, please post your opinions as comments only. Answers, on the other hand, should be based on verifiable facts, like statements by someone with definite knowledge. If there are any records of the developers discussing this fact, that would be perfect. If there is a blog post by someone inside discussing this issue, that would still be very good.

Since Stack Overflow questions should deal with real programming problems, one might argue that asking for the reason is a bad question. Getting an answer won't make that explicit lod access suddenly appear, and therefore won't help me solve my immediate problems. But I feel that the reason here might be due to some important aspect of how OpenGL ES works which I haven't grasped so far. If that is the case, then understanding the motivation behind this one decision will help me and others to better understand OpenGL ES as a whole, and therefore make better use of it in their programs, in terms of performance, exactness, portability and so on. Therefore I might have stated this question as “what am I missing?”, which feels like a very real programming problem to me at the moment.

Comment: The basic "why" is that OpenGL ES 2.0 is a relatively old API (released in 2007, based on desktop API from 2005) designed for implementation on phones back when phones were built on 130nm silicon and were not really using 3D graphics at all.  

More ways to access functionality = bigger GPU, slower drivers, and when you have a phone from 8 years ago that was viewed as a problem. Smartphones are now a lot more powerful, so the need for a really cut down API has reduced, so most of the restrictions are vanishing and mobile GPUs are now almost at feature parity with desktop GPUs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`texture2DLod (...)` serves a very important purpose in vertex shader texture lookups, which is not necessary in fragment shaders.

When a texture lookup occurs in a fragment shader, the fragment shader has access to per-attribute gradients (partial derivatives such as `dFdx (...)` and `dFdy (...)`) for the primitive currently being shaded, and it uses this information to determine which LOD to fetch neighboring texels from during filtering.

At the time vertex shaders run, no information about primitives is known and there is no such gradient. The only way to utilize mipmaps in a vertex shader is to explicitly fetch a specific LOD, and that is why that function was introduced.

Desktop OpenGL has solved this problem a little more intelligently, by offering a variant of texture lookup for vertex shaders that actually takes a gradient as one of its inputs. Said function is called `textureGrad (...)`, and it was introduced in GLSL 1.30. ESSL 1.0 is derived from GLSL 1.20, and does not benefit from all the same basic hardware functionality.

ES 3.0 does not have this limitation, and neither does desktop GL 3.0. When explicit LOD lookups were introduced into desktop GL (3.0), it could be done from any shader stage. It may just be an oversight, or there could be some fundamental hardware limitation (recall that older GPUs used to have specialized vertex and pixel shader hardware and embedded GPUs are never on the cutting edge of GPU design).

---

Whatever the original reason for this limitation, it has been rectified in a later OpenGL ES 2.0 extension and is core in OpenGL ES 3.0. Chances are pretty good that a modern GL ES 2.0 implementation will actually support explicit LOD lookups in the fragment shader given the following extension:

[`GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_texture_lod.txt)

#### Pseudo-code showing explicit LOD lookup in a fragment shader:

```
#version 100
#extension GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod : require

attribute vec2      tex_st;
uniform   sampler2D sampler;

void main (void)
{
  // Note the EXT suffix, that is very important in ESSL 1.00
  gl_FragColor = texture2DLodEXT (sampler, tex_st, 0);
}
```